# Contact picture not adding to the Contact in my application

Tags: android

i want to add the image to the contacts, but i cant add the image to the contact, but if the contact image is existing it will replace the existing image and set. but while we are going for new one it is not working ...kindly help any one ...Thanks in advance

```
try {
                    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);

                    android.content.ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
                            .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

                    builder.withSelection(
                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                            new String[] {
                                    String.valueOf(contactId),
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE });
                    builder.withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,
                            stream.toByteArray());
                    ops.add(builder.build());

                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                            ops);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

case R.id.assign_contact:

```
        cropstatus = 2;

         filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
         + "/Noredoo/Profile Pictures/" + file.getName();

         startCropImage(filepath, 1, 1);

         Intent contactintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
         ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
         startActivityForResult(
         Intent.createChooser(contactintent, "Choose Contact"),
         PICK_CONTACT);

        return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that when inserting a new image you need to use a different method as described here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html#newInsert(android.net.Uri)

When the contact doesn't already have an image it's impossible to update the field because it doesn't exists. You should perform an insert operation instead.

Here is is a sample of a working code for achieving that goal:

```
// Creating new photo entry
int rawContactId = -1;
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] {id}, null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
rawContactId =     cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));

if(rawContactId > -1) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photoBytes)
                    .build());
try {
    resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```